# phonegap code: 2 message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

am having task to find the geo location for get the current position.the problem am facing is when i run the app first time it shows the answer,if i  run the app as repeatedly means it 
shows error:

```
code: 2
message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)
```

the code is given below:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            var watchID = null;

            // PhoneGap is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Update every 3 seconds
                var options = { frequency: 3000 };
                watchID = navigator.geolocation.getPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
            }

            // onSuccess Geolocation
            //
            function onSuccess(position) {
                alert(position);
                var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
            }

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }
```

i run the app only in simulator.i don't know whats going wrong?

Comment: what did you used.?
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition 
OR 
navigator.geolocation.getPosition.?

Comment: @JDev just i used navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Comment: And what did you pass as options for watch position.?
can you please edit your question and post your full code OR function of watch position.

Comment: if you are using cordova 2.9, use this example and try.

here you have used "getPosition" with "watchID" i think you have used wrong method.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition

please use this link as reference and try.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you lost your connection. I get that error by running my app, then going into Airplane Mode. Hope that helps.